# different color for first row in JTable with pagination

Tags: java, swing, pagination, jtable, tablecellrenderer

I have a JTable with pagination.I want change the first row color in first page to pink.but when I override prepareRenderer() ,the first row in all page have pink.becuse in second page the first row has index=10 but table calcute row=0,how can do it?

```
 JTable table = new JTable(tableModel) {

        @Override
        public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer, int row, int column) {
            Component c = super.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, column);

            if (row == 0) {
                    c.setBackground(Color.PINK);
            }
            return c;
        }
    };
```

Comment: Which pagination component are you using?

Comment: Well your JTable (or TableModel) has the logic that knows which relative row is loaded into the table at any given time, so you need to add the relative row offset when calculating the absolute row being displayed.